# Green rep change notification doesn't match the actual number in the tab

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

This evening the strangest thing just happened to me. I got notified of a `+4` rep change, but when I opened the tab, I saw only an unread `+5` from (presumably) a question upvote. See the screenshot:

[image]

How did that happen? Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you downvoted an answer recently?  I wonder if you downvoted an answer that eventually got deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Can someone find the dupe source?

Comment: I remember downvoting an answer to [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26405/speak-greek-in-chinese) which is now deleted, @BenMiller, but I believe that I should have already seen the resulting -1. I vaguely remember seeing a +1 resulting from accepted edit suggestion (+2) + downvote to answer (-1), and I believe said +1 was before the many upvotes to "Bamileke language Kwa" which are seen in the screenshot.

Comment: Naturally, if the deletion of said answer reversed both the downvote -1 and the accepted edit +2, we would have a total of -1 from reversion, explaining the discrepancy.

Comment: @MickG I think you solved it. I bet that's exactly what happened.

Comment: How ironic. The same "problem" happened again with a +3 on this question reported as +5 in the green. I guess that amounts to upvote+downvote to this, right? EDIT: Well, considering the question currently scores 0, I guess it's beyond reasonable doubt that this is what happened.

Comment: @BenMiller so if a post gets deleted any rep changes due to edits on it are reversed. Good to know.